# How can I do get value in Sweet Alert Poppup Message Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I use JQUERY Datatable js and SweetAlert.js

There is a delete icon in datatable when click id get id and showing sweet alert confirm poppup . when click Yes it deleted fine working.

I want to get information about id’s = "TITLE" value to the warning message content.

**DATATABLE**

```
<tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>@item.TITLE</td>
       <td>
       **<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteuser('@item.id')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>**
       </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

> **SWEETALERT** **Js** code This Point get need here (bold marked value) => text: "@TITLE are u want delete!" id title text should come here

```
function deleteuser(userid) {
    swal({
        title: "Are u sure?",
        text: "@TITLE are u want delete!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                text: "No, iptal!",
                value: null,
                visible: true,
                className: "",
                closeModal: false,
            },
            confirm: {
                text: "Yes, sil!",
                value: true,
                visible: true,
                className: "",
                closeModal: false
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that like this:

```
<tbody id="my-table">
     <tr>
       <td class="title">Some Title</td>
       <td>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-btn" data-id="@item.id"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
       </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Later on in javascript:

```
$('#my-table').on('click', '.delete-btn', function(){
var deleteBtn = $(this),
id = deleteBtn.data('id'),
title = deleteBtn.closest('tr').find('.title').text();

swal({
        title: "Are u sure?",
        text: title + " are u want delete!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                text: "No, iptal!",
                value: null,
                visible: true,
                className: "",
                closeModal: false,
            },
            confirm: {
                text: "Yes, sil!",
                value: true,
                visible: true,
                className: "",
                closeModal: false
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Your welcome. Could you please mark the answer as correct and the answer up.